# Object enemy in unityscript

Tags: class, object, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I can do in unitycript as an object "enemy" that has "health", "speed" and "stamina". And to delete the object, or several at once?

```
class enemy {
    health = 100
    speed = 10
    stamina = 200
}

for 0 to 10
{
    enemyBig = new Enemy ()
}


if keydown (space)
{
    delete all.enemyBig 
}
```

How would this code in unityscript correctly?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but I'd suggest looking at some basic JavaScript tutorials to learn things like proper forms of `for` loops, variable scope and declaration, and event handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep track of all your enemies at once, what you need is called an **array**. There's a good tutorial there:

- http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, to define a class you create a function.

```
function Enemy {
   this.health = 100;
   ....
};
```

and then to put methods on the prototype (because javascript uses prototypal inheritance.)

```
Enemy.prototype.theMethod = function () { ... };
```

when you do the above to define a method, the method is an instance method; i.e. every object has its own copy of the method.  If you want to define a 'static' method, you just put the method on the class

```
Enemy.staticMethod = function() {...};
```

the difference is for the former you can do

```
var enemy1 = new Enemy();
enemy1.theMethod(); // this in the theMethod refers to enemy1
```

and for the latter you do

```
Enemy.staticMethod(); // there is only one staticMethod for the entire class.
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement an object:

```
function Enemy {
    this.health = 100;
    ...
};

Enemy.prototype.attack = function() {
    this.health -= 10;
    ...
};

var boogerMonster = new Enemy();
boogerMonster.attack();
```

As far as deleting an object, the garbage collector will take care of the object if it has no other references to it.

But, from the question, it looks like *just* knowing this information won't carry you far. **Grab a book** on JavaScript and/or **do some online research** to really understand the fundamentals of JavaScript.